# How to get client IP address in vercel edge functions?

Tags: node.js, api, vercel

I'm making a GET request to a Vercel edge function but can't seem to get IP Address inside API function.

all these headers values are showing `undefined`

```js
export const config = {
    runtime: "edge",
  };
  
  export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<APIResponseData>
  ) {
    
    console.log("realip", req.headers["x-real-ip"]);
    console.log("forwardedfor", req.headers["x-forwarded-for"]);
    console.log("vercelforwardedfor", req.headers["x-vercel-forwarded-for"]);
    console.log("x-vercel-ip-country", req.headers["x-vercel-ip-country"]);
  
  
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({
        data: {
          data: "ok",
        },
      }),
      {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json"
        },
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

edge function:

```js
import { ipAddress } from "@vercel/edge";
export const config = {
  runtime: "edge",
};
export default function (request: Request) {
  const ip = ipAddress(request) || "unknown";
  return;

  new Response(
    `<h1>Your IP is 
${ip}
</h1>`,
    {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "text/html",
      },
    }
  );
}
```

edge middleware:

```js
import { ipAddress } from "@vercel/edge";
export const config = {
  runtime: "edge",
};
export default function (request: Request) {
  const ip = ipAddress(request) || "unknown";
  return;

  new Response(
    `<h1>Your IP is 
${ip}
</h1>`,
    {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "text/html",
      },
    }
  );
}
```

ref: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-functions/vercel-edge-package#ipaddress

Answer (score 0):

Here are some relevant links you should check:

- [Vercel documentation on retrieving client IP address](https://vercel.com/docs/edge-network/headers#x-forwarded-for),
- [Node.js documentation on `req.socket.localAddress`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#requestsocket)

According to this, you should be able to get it with the following code:

```
export const config = {
  runtime: "edge",
};

export default async function handler(
  req,
  res
) {
  console.log({ip: req.socket.localAddress});

  return {
    status: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      data: "ok",
    }),
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: req.socket.localAddress is empty as well

Comment: What about `req.ip`?

Comment: If all this is not available, then it's not forwarded via proxy sitting in front of your serverless function.

Comment: there's no such proxy setup, It's a standard deployment to vercel.